# Changing chart x axis (category) in VBA - filter blank

Tags: vba, charts, filtering, axis

I'm trying to make a macro for charts to get more data according to the number of weeks (number of columns) above the chart. Values works perfectly, but x-axis (category) doesn't work.

1) it does not get the new data - although the range(*) itself works fine

2) data are in merged cells, I need to select them and then **filter** those empty (merged) cells.

```
Dim StartColumn As Integer
Dim EndColumn As Integer

 Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).Select
 StartColumn = Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).Column
 EndColumn = Selection.Columns.Count + StartColumn - 1

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graf_THP").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Cells(6, 4), Cells(6, EndColumn))
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(7, EndColumn))
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells(8, EndColumn))
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, EndColumn))  

' last line is where problems are...
```

This is what he's doing:
[image: this is what he's doing]

This is what I want him to do:
[image: this is what I want him to do]

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding `XValues` to each of the `SeriesCollections`. It is hard to tell if it will work in your case as I cannot fully understand what you mean by the whole merged cells and filtering empty cells as we do not have access to your data.

So my first advice would be to adapt your code to this:

```
Dim StartColumn As Integer
Dim EndColumn As Integer

StartColumn = Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).Column
EndColumn = Range("XFD3").End(xlToLeft).End(xlToRight).Column 'I have no idea what was going on here, 
'this made more sense to me, reverse this change if I made a wrong assumption.

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graf_THP")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Cells(6, 4), Cells(6, EndColumn))
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, EndColumn))
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(7, EndColumn))
    .FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, EndColumn))
    .FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = Range(Cells(8, 4), Cells(8, EndColumn))
    .FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, EndColumn))
End With
```

and see if it works.

There is also another approach which may over-complicate things, but which I had to use in one of my projects and it is kind of neat. The idea is to store x and y values of the chart as a string and then to pass it as the `FullSeriesCollection`. It may help with more complicated sorts of filtering so I will also post it below:

```
'Imagine having stored the values inside the Variant "arrayOfValues"
Dim dataX as String, dataY as String
dataX = "={" & CStr(1)
dataY = "={" & arrayOfValues.Item(1)
For j = 2 To arrayOfValues.Count
    dataX = dataX & "," & CStr(j)   'Assuming your x values range from 1 to values count
    dataY = dataY & "," & arrayOfValues(j)
Next j
dataX = dataX & "}"
dataY = dataY & "}"

myChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = dataX
myChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = dataY
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response @Lorne

- StartColumn, EndColumn = dunno aswell, found this solution on google and it's working smooth (returns the number of last column in selection - needed number for chart data range)
- your first solution was doing pretty much the same like my did
- your second solution is truly overcomplicated - i didn't get it at all :( :D
- the problem with merged cells are like this:

https://i.paste.pics/038e7044e4c410caff86a0c05ad3b4a0.png (not enough rep. to post pics, so link only)

basically, all I need to do is to filter those "blanks" (E2,F2,G2 - merged cells)